# Is the set of polynomial dense in $C[-1, 0]$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, metric-spaces

If the set is defined as 
$$\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n, \text{where }n\ge 0 \text{ and } a_0+a_1+...+a_n=0\},$$ 
is the set dense in $C[0,1]$ and $C[-1,0]$?

For the first question, I'm thinking using Weierstrass theorem that there exists a function $f$ belongs to $C[0,1]$ s.t $p_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[0,1]$. And $p_n(1)$ converges uniformly to $f(1) = 0$ and the set belongs to the new set $\{f|f(1)=0\}$ which is not $C[0,1]$. So it's not dense in $C[0,1]$. Is the idea right?

For the second question, I'm thinking proving the set is dense in $C[-1,1]$ and therefore dense in $C[-1,0]$. But I'm wondering is it possible for a set dense in $C[-1,1]$ but not in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: You are correct for the first question. You are not using the theorem though. You are assuming that $p_n \to f$ uniformly and come up with $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: The question in the title and the body do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion that this set of polynomials is not dense in $[0,1]$ is correct, but the argument is not quite right. Instead, you should choose a particular function $f\in C[0,1]$ with $f(1)\neq 0$ such that no sequence of admissible polynomials converges to $f$. Try, for instance, $f(x)=1$. The argument would hinge on the fact that no sequence of polynomials can converge pointwise to $1$ when $x=1$.

For the second question, your argument won't work. The set of polynomials is not dense in $C[-1,1]$ by the same argument you just gave. A set that is dense in $C[-1,1]$ will always have a dense set of restrictions to $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I just checked the transitive property and it says Given three subsets A, B and C of a topological space X with A ⊆ B ⊆ C such that A is dense in B and B is dense in C (in the respective subspace topology) then A is also dense in C. So i think it doesn't apply to this case.

Comment: That's right. Not to mention the fact that $C[0,1]$ is not a subset of $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit confused here. I just found another link which asks the same question as mine. Maybe Jean-Claude Arbaut illustrated the idea of extending C[-1,0] to C[-1,1] more clear in the comments below. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715895/is-the-set-of-polynomials-of-degree-n-whose-coefficients-sum-to-0-dense-over-c?rq=1

Comment: Jean-Claude Arbaut's ideas are good. I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: I'm confused because you said the set of polynomials is not dense in C[-1,1] but Jean-Claude Arbaut's ideas suggest it's dense in C[-1,1].

Comment: He never claims that your set of polynomials is dense in $C[-1,1]$. He only explains that it is possible to uniformly approximate a continuous function $g$ on $[-1,1]$ such that $g(1)=0$, not every continuous function.

Comment: I see! Thanks for explaining!